# How to get device orientation when the screen rotation is locked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, device

I used the notification to get the device's orientation.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self  
                                   selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange)           
                                       name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification 
                                     object:nil];
```

But the selector function is not called when the device's screen rotation is locked. Any help?

Comment: is "notificationCenter" correctly set ? Check if it's not nil. You can also try this syntax : [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I have locked the orientation via XCode, but using  `UIDevice.current.orientation` is giving the unlocked orientation. Even though the device is actually in landscape-left orientation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use accelerometer to get values of screen orientation. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html). Also see [this](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-accelerometer-device-orientation/) blog